Can we use maximum likelihood estimation criterion like this?
Given a random variable $r=b+n$, where $b\sim CN(0,\sigma_s^2)$, $n \sim CN(0,\sigma_n^2)$ and $b$ is independent of $n$.
Let $f(r;b,\sigma_n)$ be the PDF of $r$ conditioned on $b$ and $\sigma_{n}$
The problem is
Can I estimate $b$ like this
$$
\hat{b}=\arg\max_b f(r;b,\sigma_n)
$$
To the best of my knowledge, the MLE is typically used to estimate the statistical parameters (rather than the random components) for a random variable.
Here I write the PDF of $r$ conditioned on $b$, and then this problem is raised.
I just ask this question to figure out if this approach is theoretically correct.
Any helpful suggestions or answers will be greatly appreciated!

What does CN mean ? Contaminated normal?

Here CN stands for the complex normal distribution.
